# Can I show toast notifications in reference to an existing application shortcut?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-10, devexpress, toast

I would like to display toast notifications in windows from my WinForms application. I am using the `ToastNotificationsManager` class from DevExpress to manage the process. When the `ToastNotificationsManager` is initialized, its "ApplicationID" property has a GUID set to it, and because a shortcut in the start menu is required for the notifications to work, I click "Create Shortcut" in the smart tag to create one.

It appears to me like that ID is used in the `.lnk` shortcut file and that's how the application knows which shortcut to associate the toast notification with.

The issue is my application is installed on various peoples computers already and each computer already has a shortcut in the start menu for the application. As of now the GUID that was generated in the designer of my form is not linked to anything and the toast notification popup only show this GUID instead of the application name and icon.

**Is there a way to retrieve the application ID used in the existing shortcut file** by the installer and set that value in my `ToastNotificationsManager`? This way my updater can replace the `.exe` on everyone's computer and the messages instantly begin showing properly.

[image]

Comment: Do the existing shortcuts contain a similar GUID or is that something specific to this toast component? If they do then you can presumably search for an existing shortcut and the GUID within it and replace the value within your app. If they don't then you will presumably have to tell your users to create a new shortcut in order for notifications to work.

Comment: I believe the shortcuts do contain some kind of GUID that I could just put into the app, but my question is how do I find it?

Comment: Have you tried contacting DevExpress instead?

Comment: I could but this isn't something specific to DevExpress, this is a windows issue.